# How to set different valueTextColor in Gauge's valueText

Tags: reactjs, html-framework-7

I want to set different color for Gauge's inner text,but framework7 can't do that

Comment: Please post a codepen (or similar) sample, with what you have attempted so far.

Comment: I just can show you the official docs.I don't have done anything else.Thank You https://framework7.io/react/gauge.html

Comment: Have you tried using `labelTextColor`?

Comment: Yes it's just for whole text,but I want to separate them like "2"-is one color and "/10"-is a one color

Comment: You should post a screenshot for what you are attempting to do. If you want MULTIPLE colours for inner text, probably you need to create a custom gauge component that can have markup inside inner text and you can set colours using classes.